# reducing the verbosity of "rake spec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Every time I run "rake spec" on my Rails 3 / RSpec 2 project, the first thing it does is print out the "bundle exec spec ...." command it runs. The part I omitted, however, is a list of all the spec files in the project, which is a big chunk of text that gets in the way of reading test results. How do I turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use rake spec and instead I run my specs via rspec runner. So instead of "rake spec" I just do "rspec spec/". You can pass various options to this command as described in the first answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the output of your specs by placing flags in a `spec/spec.opts` file in your rails app.

Example from [this](http://g-lunit.blogspot.com/2008/08/rspec-format-options.html) blog post:

```
--colour
--format progress
--format specdoc:spec/spec_full_report.txt
--format failing_examples:spec/spec_failing_examples.txt
--format html:spec/spec_report.html
--loadby mtime
--reverse
```

You can see all the available options here: https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/runner/option_parser.rb

Comment: this is used by the rspec runner. not the rake task and the question is about the initial output of the rake task not the runner.

Comment: also, I'm using RSpec 2, which doesn't use spec.opts

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your Rakefile

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task(:spec).clear
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.verbose = false
end
```